# Convert multiple PARTITION BY to LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

EF Core does not have a `SqlQuery()` method yet (epic fail) so I have no way to run a query/stored proc on my database to get "summary" data.  Here is a summary query I have with multiple PARTITION BYs that I need to convert to LINQ:

```
SELECT 
    s.Name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pc.WorkflowStateId <> 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY s.SiteId) 'RegisteredCount',     
    SUM(CASE WHEN pc.WorkflowStateId = 99 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY s.SiteId) 'ScreenFailedCount'
FROM Sites s 
JOIN Patients p ON p.SiteId = s.SiteId 
JOIN PatientCycles pc ON pc.PatientId = p.PatientId
```

`Sites`, `Patients`, and `PatientCycles` are DbSets.

How can I convert this to a C# LINQ query?

**UPDATE**
This is the solution I came up with:

```
var summaries = from site in context.Sites
                let registered = (from pc in context.PatientCycles
                                    where site.SiteId == pc.Patient.SiteId && pc.WorkflowStateId != WorkflowStateType.Terminated
                                    select pc).Count()
                let terminated = (from pc in context.PatientCycles
                                    where site.SiteId == pc.Patient.SiteId && pc.WorkflowStateId == WorkflowStateType.Terminated
                                    select pc).Count()
                select new SiteSummary { Site = site, RegisteredCount = registered, ScreenFailedCount = terminated };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well an alternative in Linq would be something like this:

```
var query= from s in context.Sites
           join p in context.Patiens on s.SiteId equals p.SiteId
           join pc in context.PatientCycles on p.PatiendId equals p.PatiendId 
           group pc.WorkflowStateId by new{s.SiteId,s.Name} into g
           select new {Name=g.Key.Name,
                       RegisteredCount=g.Sum(e=>e!=99?1:0),
                       ScreenFailedCount=g.Sum(e=>e==99?1:0)
                      }
```

### Update

To avoid that kind of problem use nav. properties:

```
var query= from s in context.Sites
           select t new SiteSummary
            {
                SiteId = s.SiteId,
                Name = s.Name,
                Code = s.Code,
                RegisteredCount =s.Patiens.SelectMany(e=>e.PatientCycles.Select(y=>y.WorkflowStateId ))
                                          .Sum(x => x!= WorkflowStateType.Terminated ? 1 : 0),
                ScreenFailedCount = s.Patiens.SelectMany(e=>e.PatientCycles.Select(y=>y.WorkflowStateId ))
                                             .Sum(x => x== WorkflowStateType.Terminated ? 1 : 0)
            };
```

Also I suggest to initialize the collection navigation properties in entity constructors:

```
public class Sites
{
  //...
  public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients{get;set;}
  public Sites()
  { 
    Patients=new List<Patient>();
  }
}
```

Comment: I just realized this will only return Sites with patient cycles.  How can I alter this query to return sites (with counts of 0) if there are no patients/patientcycles.

Comment: In that case I think you are going to need to do left joins instead of inner joins, check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to see how to do it.

Comment: "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."